# Safe to reduce swap size Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, swap

I recently dual booted my laptop with Windows 10 and Kali Linux. It was successful and both OS's work fine.

My only mistake was making a 6Gb swap partition.

I would like to know if it is safe to reduce swap space using GParted, and then use the freed up space for the Kali partition. All my Google searches brought up sites for *increasing* swap, even though my searches said *decrease*. If possible, I would also like to know the purpose for swap and what benefits it has for the system, along with the impacts of different swap sizes.

My laptop has 4.00Gb of RAM, Intel i5, 128Gb Samsung SSD.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but use [swapoff](http://linux.die.net/man/8/swapoff) first (or a live CD).
With 4GB RAM you likely don't need a swap at all.
Generally swap (used by linux and windows) is there so when your computer runs out of RAM it won't crash or be forced to kill apps to keep running.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll try that out. I was originally trying to install without swap, but the installer wouldn't let me continue without it, strangely.